# two hyperlink inside a <li> list item

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, listitem

How to insert two hyperlinks side by side inside an li item?

In the html code below, I need to put "login"  and "register" link side by side separated by a "|". What modification is required in the below code to accomplish the task.

Thanks.

The html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html> 
<html> 
<head> 
        <link href="styledel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head> 

<body>
<div id="navcontainer">
                <ul id="navlist">   
                     <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php">The Tool </a>                       
                        <ul id="subnavlist">
                            <li><a href="subtitle1.php" target = "_blank">Secondary Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="tutorials.php">Tutorials &AMP; FAQs</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php" target="_blank">Login</a> | <a href="user_add.php" target="_blank">Register</a></li>      
        </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The css file:

```
#navcontainer
{
border-right: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 0px;  /* menu look*/
font-family: 'Courier New',Courier,monospace;
background-color: #d4cfcf;
}

#navcontainer ul
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: none;
}

#navcontainer li
{

border-bottom: 1px solid #90bade; /*separator*/
margin: 0;
}

#navcontainer li a  /*menu */
{
display: block;
padding: 5px .3em 5px .3em;
border-left: .3em solid #1958b7;
border-right: .3em solid #508fc4;
color: #004963;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navcontainer li a:hover  /*behavior on hover */
{
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #ad0000; 
}

#navcontainer li li   /*sub menu*/
{   
border-top: 1px solid #90bade;
border-bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Courier New',Courier,monospace;
font-size: 13px;
}

#    navcontainer li li a  /* sub menu */
{
padding: 4px 4px 4px 15px;
color: #5b6f7b /* light slate color: #00788a  color of text */
}
/* navigation menu end */
```

Thanks a ton.

Comment: can u pl elaborate. What do I need to add in css file? How to reference that in html file? Nothing happens if I add the above line into my css file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching a little of the CSS out from the `<a>` tag to the `<li>` element instead, like below, where you remove `display:block` from the `li a` and move the border-decoration to the `li`.  Then, where you have `#navcontainer li li`, remove the border-decoration by setting `border-left:0px` and `border-right:0px;`

```
#navcontainer  li
{
 padding: 5px .3em 5px .3em;
 border-left: .3em solid #1958b7;
border-right: .3em solid #508fc4;
border-bottom: 1px solid #90bade; /*separator*/
margin: 0;
}





color: #004963;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navcontainer li a:hover  /*behavior on hover */
{
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #ad0000; 
}

#navcontainer li li   /*sub menu*/
{   
border-top: 1px solid #90bade;
border-bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Courier New',Courier,monospace;
font-size: 13px;
border-left:0px;
border-right:0px;
}

#navcontainer li li a  /* sub menu */
{
padding: 4px 4px 4px 15px;
color: #5b6f7b /* light slate color: #00788a  color of text */
}
/* navigation menu end */​
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please add some explanation of what changes you've made, and what those changes will do to help resolve the problem. Also, you're probably aware (given that you've a rep > 400), but you might want to take a look at the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) pages for guidance on formatting.

Comment: Was trying to add that in I think while you were posting this.

Comment: Ah, in which case I'm sorry for holding you up... =/

Comment: Changing "navcontainer li a" solve the purpose but it mess up with all other  settings.

Comment: Have you implemented all the changes?  Please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/EjS7v/14/.  I have looked at it in Chrome, FF and IE 7-9 and it seems to be working like you want.

Comment: @DaveThomas, no worries friend!  :)

Answer (score 1):

UAs the code is now, the links should be side by side. If they arn't, it's because they don't have enough space. This could be because you're setting a width that's too small, or the margins and paddings reduced the available space.

If you want the list items to be in one line, you use `display:inline` on them

```
#nav li{display:inline}
ul{list-style:none;} /* because you don't want a list with inline items to have bullets. */
```

Comment: I think width is not a problem as the two links are shown in different lines. Some of my text is longer than these two.

Comment: Not helping, (login, | , register) spans into three lines